# Why do i have to click twice?

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login page where i have to : insert user and password (1 time); click the button(the login button) twice to actually login.I use Xamp with PHP 5.3 and HeidiSQL .If i'm already in session, it skips the login window and redirects to content page else the form is submitted(which is what i want it to do).This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
 session_start();
 include("../conect.php");



 if(isset($_SESSION['name']))

 { 
    $username = $_SESSION['name']; 
    $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
        {
                if ($pass != $info[2]){
                    header('.<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>.');  
                }

                else
                    {   if($_SESSION['role']==0) 
                        header("Location: content0.php");

                        if($_SESSION['role']==1) 
                        header("Location: content1.php");

                        if($_SESSION['role']==2) 
                        header("Location: content2.php");
                    }
        }
 }


 //if the login form is submitted 

 if (isset($_POST['login'])) { 
    $nume=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $parola=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
    if((!$_POST['username']) || (!$_POST['pass'])) {

        die('You did not fill in a required field.');

    }

    $check_pass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$nume'")or die(mysql_error());
    $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check_pass);

    if ($check2 == 0) {
        die("That user does not exist in our database");
    }

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array( $check_pass )) {
            //gives error if the password is wrong
            if ($parola != $data[2]) {

                die('Incorrect password, please try again.');
            }
            else {  
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$nume'")or die(mysql_error());
                        while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                            $_SESSION['name']=$data[1];
                            $_SESSION['pass']=$data[2];
                            $_SESSION['role']=$data[3];
                        }
                    }
                } 

} 


mysql_close($con);
?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/butoane.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_tools.css" type="text/css" />
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body id="login_background">

<div id="ambele">
<div class="form_box">

    <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="40"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" id="password"name="pass" maxlength="20"/>
    <input type="submit" name ="login" value="Login" class="button"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="register"> 
<a href="registration_form.php" id="reg">Not registered yet? Go to Registration</a>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to exit your script to do redirection.

```
<?php
header('Location: content.php');
die();
?>
```

Also, you put the PHP tag in the wrong position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
[...]
?>
[...]
```

This will cause the `Headers already sent` error in PHP because you already send something to the client before you do redirection.

Comment: i added the "die();" nothing changed as for the tags they are ok because after "?>" comes html code

Comment: You should put the PHP tag at the first line to do redirection or else it'll have error.

Comment: Figured it out . The problem was that when i submitted i forgot to do the redirect , so when i clicked the second time it went in the first IF and did redirect from there :).